# Wordpress Undefined property: stdClass::$post_type

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting this error on my blog did some one had the same error? how can i fix the error?
I didnt edited any File.

```
  Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$post_type in /home/a4673438/public_html/wp-includes/link-template.php on line 105

  Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$post_status in /home/a4673438/public_html/wp-includes/link-template.php on line 112

  Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$post_type in /home/a4673438/public_html/wp-includes/link-template.php on line 105

  Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$post_status in /home/a4673438/public_html/wp-includes/link-template.php on line 112

  Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$post_type in /home/a4673438/public_html/wp-includes/link-template.php on line 105

  Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$post_status in /home/a4673438/public_html/wp-includes/link-template.php on line 112
  Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$post_type in /home/a4673438/public_html/wp-includes/link-template.php on line 105

  Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$post_status in /home/a4673438/public_html/wp-includes/link-template.php on line 112


  Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$post_type in /home/a4673438/public_html/wp-includes/link-template.php on line 105


  Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$post_status in /home/a4673438/public_html/wp-includes/link-template.php on line 112
```

code causing this errors 
**line 112**

```
if ( '' != $permalink && !in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending')) ) {
    $unixtime = strtotime($post->post_date);
```

**line 105**

```
if ( $post->post_type == 'page' )
        return get_page_link($post->ID, $leavename, $sample);
```

Comment: Could you post the code that is generating this? It makes the debugging process a bit more... possible :-]

Comment: hy thanks, debugging isnt activated in wp, i can but i didnt, this output was generated when i called the main index.php as usual i would visid my blog

Comment: I meant; we need to see the code so we can figure out what is going on. According to the error message, a standard (mostly empty) class is being used as if it were something else. Beyond that I can't really say. Need da codez :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these lines *after* line #100 in that file:

```
if($post == null) {
    return '';
}
```

That might fix the errors, but it might cause side effects in the page. Missing permanent links to your posts, to be exact.

What version of WordPress are you using, anyways?